# Reading a file and output in a particular format in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a text file containing some data. as I am not a good programmer I am not able solve my problem. The text file is something like:

```
00000001 ggccgccggcggtatcatggcgacccggaacccccctccccaag 00000044
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44121210 ggccgccggcggtatcatggcgacccggaacccccctccccaag 44121167

00000045 actatgaaagtgatgatgactcttacgaagtgttggatttaactgagtat 00000094
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120443 actatgaaagtgatgatgactcttacgaagtgttggatttaactgagtat 44120394

00000095 gccagaagacaccactggtggaatcgagtgtttggccacagttccggacc 00000144
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120393 gccagaagacaccactggtggaatcgagtgtttggccacagttccggacc 44120344

00000145 tatggtagaaaaatactcagtggccacccagattgtaatgggtggagtga 00000194
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120343 tatggtagaaaaatactcagtggccacccagattgtaatgggtggagtga 44120294

00000195 gtggctg 00000201
<<<<<<<< ||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120293 gtggctg 44120287

00000202 gtgtgcaggatttttgttccagaaagttggaaaacttgcagcaactgcag 00000251
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44116963 gtgtgcaggatttttgttccagaaagttggaaaacttgcagcaactgcag 44116914

00000252 taggtggtggctttcttcttcttcag 00000277
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44116913 taggtggtggctttcttcttcttcag 44116888

00000278 atcgccagtcacagtggctatgtgcagatcgactggaagagagttgaaaa 00000327
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44113328 atcgccagtcacagtggctatgtgcagatcgactggaagagagttgaaaa 44113279

00000328 agatgtaaacaaagcaaaaagacagattaagaaacgagcaaataaggcag 00000377
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44113278 agatgtaaacaaagcaaaaagacagattaagaaacgagcaaataaggcag 44113229

00000378 cacctgaaatcaacaacataattgaagaa 00000406
<<<<<<<< ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44113228 cacctgaaatcaacaacataattgaagaa 44113200

00000407 gcaacagaatttgtcaaacagaacattgtcatatccagtggatttgtggg 00000456
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44111361 gcaacagaatttgtcaaacagaacattgtcatatccagtggatttgtggg 44111312

00000457 aggctttttgctaggccttgcatcttaaggatatgaatgatctatcccag 00000506
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44111311 aggctttttgctaggccttgcatcttaaggatatgaatgatctatcccag 44111262
```

this is a blat output file.

What I want is put the value corresponding assign the lower lines values to the upper line values like this:

```
00000001- 44121210
00000002- 44121211
00000003- 44121212
00000004- 44121213
-
-
-
00000506- 44111262.
```

Comment: `g,c,t,a`, just curious, is this DNA?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  The number 00000002 does not appear in the sample input; how does it get to appear in the sample output?  The number 44121211 does not appear in the sample input; how does it get to appear in the sample output?  More generally, what is the output expected from the example input you show?  Your sample output does not bear sufficient resemblance to the input for us to know what to do.  Also, more generally, what have you tried?

Comment: sorry i am just new to this.whats happening is that the sequence is itself the numbers.ooooooo1 is g and following g is 00000002

Comment: yes YU Hao this is the dna sequence and this is the sample blat output

Comment: Please show the output you expect from the input you show — not the output you expect from some other data set, or more complete form of the input data you show.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think it is expected output except the second column should go down. See mine solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what you want:

```
perl -F'\s' -anE'BEGIN{$/="\n\n";}$i=$F[6];say"$_ - ",$i--for($F[0]..$F[2])'
```

Simple, isn't it?

BTW, your example output is wrong. I see the image (copy) mirrored. Left value is bigger than right. So values in second column should go down. If it can vary in your input data you have to use little bit longer solution.

```
perl -F'\s' -anE'BEGIN{$/="\n\n";}$i=$F[6];say"$_ - ",$i<$F[8]?$i++:$i--for($F[0]..$F[2])'
```

There is normal script version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = '\n\n';
$\ = '\n';

while (<>) {
    my ( $f, $t, $i, $j ) = ( split ' ' )[ 0, 2, 6, 8 ];
    print "$_ - ", $i < $j ? $i++ : $i-- for ( $f .. $t );
}
```

**Edit**:

How it works? `$/ = '\n\n';` switches reading into paragraph mode. ("Lines" are separated by two ends of line.) `$\ = '\n';` adds end of line after each `print` invocation. Using `say` instead of `print` will do same thing but you have to use `use feature 'say';` or `-E` switch. `split ' '` or `-F'\s'` splits read paragraph by white chars which includes end of line. (Note `' '` has special meaning in `split` invocation.) Then it uses 1st, 3rd, 7th and 9th "word" (indexes 0,2,6,8) to determine which coordinates should be printed. `$f .. $t` generates original coordinates and `$i` is starting point for image coordinates. `$i < $j` chooses direction of image coordinates and `$i < $j ? $i++ : $i--` just generates them. Suffix `for` is pretty Perl idiomatic way how to iterate trough the generated original coordinates.

Comment: I ran these scripts on the data shown in the question, and I don't see how your output (generating 506 lines) corresponds to the input (which has 12 sets of input).  The first line of your output corresponds to the first line of output in my answer, and to the first line of output in the question.  Thereafter, there are 3 different opinions (at least) on what the output should be.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The input is DNA and numbers corresponds to positions. There are sequences found on different places. First line is original and third line is image. Each line corresponds to one amine-acid left column is original position and second column is its copy. There are 506 amine-acids in input so there are 506 lines in output.

Comment: We're going to have to agree to disagree on the interpretation of the data until the OP clarifies what is wanted. I can't say "I'm right, you're wrong" or vice versa.  The other two answers produce the same output as mine, but majority voting doesn't count in a situation like this.

Comment: this gives:                                                      Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "n\"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "n\"
BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted at -e line 1.@Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil

Comment: @dhaliwal There is not any "n\" in mine code. I have used copy paste with both one-liners and both are working as expected. Use copy paste. Don't try write it by hand if you are not experienced Perl hacker.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil.now when i run this one liner it gives:Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.please help.

Comment: @dhaliwal There is may be missing `'` at the end. You have to copy the whole line. I have tested it again a it works.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil i have check it again.i copied your onliner and pasted it as it is on my command line as: C:\Perl\bin>perl -F'\n' -anE'BEGIN{$/="\n\n";}($f,$t,$i,$j)=(map{split/ /}@F)[0,
2,6,8];say"$_ - ",$i<$j?$i++:$i--for($f..$t)' <gh.txt
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1. where gh.txt is my input file.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil-i am using active perl v5.10.1

Comment: @dhaliwal Oh Windows, I would not expect anybody is still using it. It seems like your shell has some serious problem to parse line correctly. I will try add normal script version.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil:thanx.i can wait.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil:thank you so very much.it worked.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil:again can you please explain me how it works.

Comment: @dhaliwal I added explanation. I thought it is pretty straightforward idiomatic Perl code.

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil:if in the beginning if i have the name of the sequence and the chromosome number mentioned like for example contig1 chromosome 5 then how to print the alignment results.output format contig1 chromosome 5 00000607 - 44111161
contig1 chromosome 5 00000608 - 44111160
contig1 chromosome 5 00000609 - 44111159
contig1 chromosome 5 00000610 - 44111158
contig1 chromosome 5 00000611 - 44111157
contig1 chromosome 5 00000612 - 44111156
contig1 chromosome 5 00000613 - 44111155
and so on.and in alignment at some places i have missing | and a,c,g,t replaced by . symbol.please help

Comment: something like this:                                                                 contig 1                                                           chromosome 5                                                           00000001 gaggagccc.acagcgagc.cacagcccgagagctcgag 00000049
>>>>>>>> ||||||||| | ||||||| ||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>
64060851 gaggagcccaagagcgagcgcacagcccgagagctcgag 64060900                              
                                                                                                                       i would be grateful to you sir for your help. thanx

Comment: @dhaliwal I'm afraid it leads in whole new solution and may be formulated as new question. In your example it seems there should be only skipped some positions. Can be there also insertions and deletions? Those are the questions which you should address in your new question and provide examples of as mach as possible variants.

Comment: Look there is 39 letters in your input sequence and same amount in your output sequence but input coordinates spreads across 44 positions and output across 49 positions. Your example data seems inconsistent to me. It is hard to provide solution with buggy examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that the reason `00000002` does not appear in the example input is because is not complete, and also is unsorted.

(I did read what you wrote:

> the sequence is itself the numbers.ooooooo1 is g and following g is 00000002

But I'm sorry, I didn't understand that explanation)

So if I understand it/guess it correctly, you want to take those lines, take the first number of the first line of the block (like `00000001`) and join it with the first number of the third line of the block (in that block, it would be `44121210`). And also that you want to sort them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# sortdna.pl

my $string = join('', <>);
my @processed = map { 
   my @l = split /\n/;
   $l[0] =~ s/\s.*$//;
   $l[2] =~ s/\s.*$//;
   $l[0] . "-" . $l[2]
} split(/\n\s*\n/, $string);
print join "\n", sort { $a cmp $b } @processed;
```

And you use it like: `perl sortdna.pl < dna.txt`

The output I get using your example input is:

```
00000001-44121210
00000045-44120443
00000095-44120393
00000145-44120343
00000195-44120293
00000202-44116963
00000252-44116913
00000278-44113328
00000328-44113278
00000378-44113228
00000407-44111361
00000457-44111311
```

...I know that I may be **way off** XD. Please, explain what exactly is what you need, and I'll edit it ;)

Comment: thanks for this. but my point is that the 00000001 upto 00000457 are the positions of the letters in the sequence ggccgccggcggtatcatggcgacccggaacccccctccccaag and these positions have corresponding 44121210 upto 44121310 positions.i want to print them in this way 00000001-44121210 00000002-44121211 00000003-44121213 upto 00000457-44121310

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------

use English   qw( -no_match_vars );  # Avoids regex performance penalty

# --------------------------------------

# saved data to be sorted
my %data = ();

# isolate the localization of $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR
{
  # paragraphs separated by a blank line
  local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = "\n\n";

  # read a paragraph
  while( my $paragraph = <DATA> ){

    # break the paragraph into lines
    my @lines = split /\n/, $paragraph;

    # key is the first integer of the first line
    my ( $key ) = $lines[0] =~ m{ \A (\d+) }msx;

    # value is the first integer of the 3rd line
    my ( $value ) = $lines[2] =~ m{ \A (\d+) }msx;

    # save the data
    $data{$key} = $value;

  } # end while DATA
} # end isolation block

# output the data sorted by keys
for my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data ){
  print "$key- $data{$key}\n";
}


__DATA__
00000001 ggccgccggcggtatcatggcgacccggaacccccctccccaag 00000044
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44121210 ggccgccggcggtatcatggcgacccggaacccccctccccaag 44121167

00000045 actatgaaagtgatgatgactcttacgaagtgttggatttaactgagtat 00000094
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120443 actatgaaagtgatgatgactcttacgaagtgttggatttaactgagtat 44120394

00000095 gccagaagacaccactggtggaatcgagtgtttggccacagttccggacc 00000144
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120393 gccagaagacaccactggtggaatcgagtgtttggccacagttccggacc 44120344

00000145 tatggtagaaaaatactcagtggccacccagattgtaatgggtggagtga 00000194
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120343 tatggtagaaaaatactcagtggccacccagattgtaatgggtggagtga 44120294

00000195 gtggctg 00000201
<<<<<<<< ||||||| <<<<<<<<
44120293 gtggctg 44120287

00000202 gtgtgcaggatttttgttccagaaagttggaaaacttgcagcaactgcag 00000251
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44116963 gtgtgcaggatttttgttccagaaagttggaaaacttgcagcaactgcag 44116914

00000252 taggtggtggctttcttcttcttcag 00000277
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44116913 taggtggtggctttcttcttcttcag 44116888

00000278 atcgccagtcacagtggctatgtgcagatcgactggaagagagttgaaaa 00000327
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44113328 atcgccagtcacagtggctatgtgcagatcgactggaagagagttgaaaa 44113279

00000328 agatgtaaacaaagcaaaaagacagattaagaaacgagcaaataaggcag 00000377
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44113278 agatgtaaacaaagcaaaaagacagattaagaaacgagcaaataaggcag 44113229

00000378 cacctgaaatcaacaacataattgaagaa 00000406
<<<<<<<< ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44113228 cacctgaaatcaacaacataattgaagaa 44113200

00000407 gcaacagaatttgtcaaacagaacattgtcatatccagtggatttgtggg 00000456
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44111361 gcaacagaatttgtcaaacagaacattgtcatatccagtggatttgtggg 44111312

00000457 aggctttttgctaggccttgcatcttaaggatatgaatgatctatcccag 00000506
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
44111311 aggctttttgctaggccttgcatcttaaggatatgaatgatctatcccag 44111262
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your data file (name `input.blat`) and the following script:

#### `unblat.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    next if m/^$/;
    my $line1 = $_;
    my $junk  = <>;
    my $line2 = <>;
    next unless $junk =~ m/^[<]+ [|]+ [<]+$/;
    $line1 =~ s/ .*//;
    $line2 =~ s/ .*//;
    printf "%.8d - %.8d\n", $line1, $line2;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ perl unblat.pl input.blat
00000001 - 44121210
00000045 - 44120443
00000095 - 44120393
00000145 - 44120343
00000195 - 44120293
00000202 - 44116963
00000252 - 44116913
00000278 - 44113328
00000328 - 44113278
00000378 - 44113228
00000407 - 44111361
00000457 - 44111311
$
```

If that's not what you want, then you must show what you want from the given data, rather than leaving us to speculate on what is the correct output from the given data.

Comment: the input file is a blat output file which shows the alignment of two sequences.the first line is the first sequence and the third line is the second sequence.the numbers 00000001 and so on are the positions of the characters in the sequence ggc....and similarly in the third line.the required output is:
00000001-44121210  000000002-44121211 00000003-44121212 upto 00000504-44111264 00000505-44111263 00000506-44111262