# to read a blat alignment file and print all the position in the alignment

Tags: perl

hello everyone i have some data form the blat tool which gives output of the alignment something like this:

```
contig30
chromosome 1
000000001 gctctgc.tctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 000000043
>>>>>>>>> ||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123368567 gctctgcatctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 123368610

000000044 tttctttgacaatgtctaccgttcatgaaattctgtgcaagctcagcttg 000000093
>>>>>>>>> |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123380141 tttctttgacaatgtctaccgttcatgaaattctgtgcaagctcagcttg 123380190

contig35
chromosome 1
000000001 gctctgc.tctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 000000043
>>>>>>>>> ||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123368567 gctctgcatctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 123368610
```

I have a text file of this data.

What I want to do is print the output in the following way:

```
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000001-123368567
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000002-123368568
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000003-123368569

 -
 -
 upto
 contig 30 chromosome 1 000000093-123380190
```

and similary for the next  entry.
I have multiple entries of this type in my input text file.

Comment: Please show your code and describe the problem you're having getting it to work.

Comment: This is related to [Reading a file and output in a particular format in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895101/reading-a-file-and-output-in-a-particular-format-in-perl).

Comment: and asked by the same user ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $contig;
my $chromo;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    if (/^contig(\d+)/)
    {
        $contig = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^chromosome (\d+)/)
    {
        $chromo = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^(\d+) [acgt.]+ (\d+)/)
    {
        my $b1 = $1;
        my $e1 = $2;
        my $junk = <>;
        my $line = <>;
        next unless $junk =~ m/^[<>]+ [ |]+ [<>]+$/; # See other question
        my($b2, $e2) = $line =~ m/^(\d+) [acgt.]+ (\d+)/;
        for (my $i = 0; $i < $e1 - $b1; $i++)
        {
            printf "contig %d chromosome %d %.9d-%.9d\n", $contig, $chromo, $b1+$i, $b2+$i;
        }
    }
    # else blank?  Ignore it, anyway.
}
```

The data in the other question has `<` instead of `>` at the start of the lines, so I've used the pattern `[<>]` to match the start and ends of the filler lines.  There are also blanks in the intermediate section in this question.

Sample output:

```
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000001-123368567
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000002-123368568
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000003-123368569
...
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000040-123368606
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000041-123368607
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000042-123368608
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000044-123380141
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000045-123380142
contig 30 chromosome 1 000000046-123380143
...
contig 35 chromosome 1 000000001-123368567
contig 35 chromosome 1 000000002-123368568
contig 35 chromosome 1 000000003-123368569
...
contig 35 chromosome 1 000000040-123368606
contig 35 chromosome 1 000000041-123368607
contig 35 chromosome 1 000000042-123368608
```

Comment: :thanx a lot.it has worked. but it does not take care of the '.' in the alignment.and also if somewhere we have chromosome number as X or M it shows 0.can you please help. thanx a lot.

Comment: again also please explain what happening in this script.

Comment: You haven't showed any examples of X or M, and you've not shown how the `.` should be handled.  You cannot expect people to guess what tricks you've got hidden up your sleeve!  You will need to work on those issues on your own.  You didn't provide enough information for the last question; you didn't provide enough information for this question.  There's a strong pattern here — one you need to break.

Answer (score 1):

May you look for something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $content = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>
};

while (
    $content =~ /   
                        (contig)(30)\n
                        (chromosome\ 1)\n
                        (\d+).*\n
                        .*\n
                        (\d+).*\n

                    /gmx
  )
{
    print $1, " ", $2, " ", $3, " ", $4, "-", $5, "\n";
}

__DATA__
contig30
chromosome 1
000000001 gctctgc.tctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 000000043
>>>>>>>>> ||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123368567 gctctgcatctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 123368610

000000044 tttctttgacaatgtctaccgttcatgaaattctgtgcaagctcagcttg 000000093
>>>>>>>>> |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123380141 tttctttgacaatgtctaccgttcatgaaattctgtgcaagctcagcttg 123380190

contig35
chromosome 1
000000001 gctctgc.tctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 000000043
>>>>>>>>> ||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123368567 gctctgcatctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 123368610

contig30
chromosome 1
000000002 gctctgc.tctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 000000043
>>>>>>>>> ||||||| |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| >>>>>>>>>
123368568 gctctgcatctggggacgctcgcagcgctcggcgcctggcccag 123368610
```

The important thing here is, that `DATA` is slurped into `$content`. That means the whole content of the file is stored into `$content` including all the newlines etc.. In order to

With the file mirrored into the variable you can perform a multiline search on it. In order to inform perl to do so you have to add the `m` modifier to the regex (the x modifier is added to improve the legibility of the regex by depicting the underlying structure of the pattern).

Comment: please set `$/` just `local` to undef!

Comment: Thanks for the hint! You are right it's better to limit the scope of the modified `$/`.